# Remove substring (URL) from a string (URL) with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having problems removing the baseUrl from a Url.

I have to string

```
var baseUrl = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
var Url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/test/number/';
Url.replace(baseUrl, "");
```

Now i would expect the result to be `/test/number/` but it does not remove the first part of the string.

The Code is an example. I do not always know for sure if the baseUrl is a substring so I cannot cut the length.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the string by returning value of [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method since  the method won't updates the string.

```js
var baseUrl = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
var Url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/test/number/';
Url = Url.replace(baseUrl, "");

console.log(Url);
```

---

Using [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof) methods.

```js
var baseUrl = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
var Url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/test/number/';
var i = Url.indexOf(baseUrl);
Url = Url.substring(0,i) + Url.substring(i + baseUrl.length);

console.log(Url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also another solution I found in Stackoverflow. 
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```